# What open source .Net utility projects or code libraries do you use?

Tags: .net, open-source, utility

I use log4net in just about every code project. I was wondering what other generally useful code projects are available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Rhino.Mocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx)
- [NUnit](http://nunit.org)
- [NHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/343.html)
- [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/)
- [Castle](http://www.castleproject.org/)
- My own somewhat eclectic [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil)
- [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I like the C5 collection classes, from the IT University of Copenhagen:

http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/

It's one of the most well-designed libraries, of any kind, I've ever used.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful open source tools/projects I've used in .NET development:

- [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)
- [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)
- [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)
- [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)

Answer (score 0):

- [Castle ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html)
- [ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Many of the ones already mentioned, plus

- [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/)
- [Fast CSV reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to agree with Jon Skeet, except that if you had to name just one, I would start with NUnit.

Please, test your code!

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a class library called SixPack

http://code.google.com/p/sixpack-library/

Answer (score 0):

For PDF manipulation
[iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net)